# Adding Xamarin ContentPage causes error in latest version of 2017

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to create a basic cross-platform app using Xamarin forms in Visual Studio 2017 (latest version) and I am experiencing all kinds of problems.

Platform: Android, iOS.
UI Technology: Xamarin.Forms
Code Sharting Strategy: Shared Project

When I do the following: 
Right click project > Add > New Item... > Content Page

```
Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.

The project system has encountered an error.

Did not find new element in the hierarchy for item `Views\MyPage.xaml`.
The item would have been added with type "Page".
The project item schema service knows about this item type.
The item does exist in the project file.
```

It still adds the files because I see them in windows explorer. In the Solution explorer MyPage.xaml is not included in the project (and I am unable to include it). MyPage.xaml.cs is included.

I saw a work around on another post, but it isn't working for me.

Does Microsoft spend anytime supporting Xamarin forms in VS2017? I never experience issues like this when doing web development.

Comment: It would be probably pretty useful to include the type of forms project it is, is it .net standard is it pcl or shared projects. What version of visual studio are you using professional or enterprise. have you tried reinstalling vs or xamarin...  have you tried running vs in safemode. all these things might help other people